# How can I attach membership database to my own database on the fly with EF code first?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-membership

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue please :

Well I'm recently building a CMS using ASP.NET MVC 4.5 ,with Entity Framework Code First , so my whole database get created on the fly , now the problem is that I need to use the built-in asp.net membership database without ending up with two databases one for the users and roles managements and one for the CMS management , so how can I solve this issue , any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the link below, let me know if you have any other questions.

[Including Asp.net Simple Membership Tables as Part of Your Entity Framework Model](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model)

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted this article is more than helpful

Comment: link is broken :(